# How to get DivX videos to play in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, codecs

After hunting quite a bit and installing various codecs / packages, I've failed to find a way to get DivX videos to play in Chrome.

Any pointers?

- Ubuntu 14.10 utopic x64
- Chrome 40.0.2214.38 (beta)

Answer (score 1):

[Xvid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvid) is a H.263 compatible format. [DivX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divx) is a company name and a trademark, but **not a particular codec**. Initially it was some flavour of H.263, then H.264 and the latest entry is [H.265](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.265).

Chrome should by default be able to play H.264 content on Ubuntu. Chromium – the open source version of Google Chrome – has a package named `chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra` for that purpose.

If I recall correctly, then no particular codec was defined for the video element in HTML5. The various custom DivX formats however never were popular in that discussion and shouldn't be used for publishing on the web.